# IE7's float right property

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have the follow code:

```
// CSS
.foo strong {
    float: right;
}

// HTML
<div class="foo">
    foo
    <strong>bar</strong>
</div>
```

And want to float the "strong' to right, but IE7 don't recognize the action..

Wrong

[image]

Correct

[image]

Comment: Try putting the `bar` before the `foo`.

Comment: What **animuson** said and also try wrapping "foo" in a tag.

Comment: Perfect! May you post a answer, to close this questuion?

Comment: @Gabriel: I would have, but I don't like posting incomplete answers, and that comment was kind of a "on the way out the door throw-it-out-there" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="foo">
    <strong>bar</strong>
    foo
</div>
```

animuson already answered, so He deserves the vote and if you need to close it for any reason you may go on but you should for  animuson's answer.